# how to insert number format function on the table query?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table query with a price value. the value has a decimal places already but don't have comma. the query displays with no comma. now my problem is yhe query dsplay is with table format. Where I will insert the number_format?

here's my code.

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) 

{
echo "
    <tr>
        <td style='border:1px solid; color:gray' width='125px' align='center'>".$row['tranid']."</td>
        <td style='border:1px solid; color:gray' width='145px' align='center'>".$row['trandate']."</td>
        <td style='border:1px solid; color:gray' width='600px'>".$row['trandescription']."</td>
        <td style='border:1px solid; color:gray' width='75px' align='center'>".$row['tranquantity']."</td>
        <td style='border:1px solid; color:gray' width='90px' align='right'>".$row['tranunitprice']."</td>
        <td style='border:1px solid; color:gray' width='150px' align='right'>".$row['tranamount']."</td>
        </tr> ";
}
```

Comment: You should clarify a bit your request and  post also  current output and expected output

Comment: what i mean is how will i insert number_format function within <td>here --> <td>.$row['tranunitprice'].</td> so the display of the price is with comma.

Comment: current output from table is 1000.00, I want a comma display also to specify a thousand amount. since there are multiple row in the table with different amount. usually i assign a variable like this --> $amount = format_number($unitprice,2); but between <td> how will insert the number_format function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example:

```
<td style='border:1px solid; color:gray' width='90px' align='right'>" . number_format($row['tranunitprice']) . "</td>
```

This should produce the result you desire.

Comment: thank you dlporter98. I just add a comma and 2 and thats it it works.